# File size check doesn't work completely

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to upload a file. When I check the file size,
`if file_size < limit` just works without any problems, but when
`file_size > limit` it does not show the error (which is an echo).

```
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
        if(isset($_POST['order']) && !empty($_POST['order'])){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
                $upload_types= array('application/x-rar-compressed','application/octet-stream','application/zip','application/octet-stream');
                if (!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $upload_types)){
                    echo "file type error";
                }
                elseif($_FILES['file']['size'] > 10000000){
                    echo "file size error";
                }
                else{
                    $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order']);
                    $query=mysql_query("SELECT `shop-id` FROM `orders` WHERE `id`='{$id}'");
                    $query=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    $query=mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `shops` WHERE `id`='{$query['shop-id']}' AND `uid`='{$_SESSION['uid']}'");
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$id.get_ext($_FILES['file']['type']));
                    }
                    else{
                        HEADER("Location:user.php?error=1");
                    };
                };
            }
            else{
                HEADER("Location:user.php?error=2");
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the limit you are talking about a soft limit you set in your script and smaller than the php.ini values `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`? If the file is bigger than these two php values the `$_FILES` array will be empty.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thanks, i guess that is the problem, but how can i check if $_FILES array is empty and show file size error?

Comment: Well the problem is you would have to use and make a hidden input and fill in the filename or just check if the array is empty and display an error like `No file selected or filesize bigger than the limit`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois how to check if the array is empty? like this : empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) ? it's not working.

Comment: `if(empty($_FILES)) {` should work

Comment: @CharlotteDunois didn't work! no problem, i just set php.ini values to 20mb and set php script limit 10 mb if file size was: 10<size<20 it will show the error otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $errors     = array();
    $maxsize    = 2097152;
    $acceptable = array(
        'application/pdf',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png'
    );

    if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0)) {
        $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
    }

    if(!in_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]))) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only PDF, JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
    }

    if(count($errors) === 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmpname'], '/store/to/location.file');
    } else {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
        }

        die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but it didn't work. i think i should check if file size is more than php.ini values by another way.